# Localized Text Not Showing Properly for bootstrap Alert using Modal class

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, localization

I have the following code:

```
$("#confirmDiv").confirmModal({
  heading: '@Language.ConfirmActionHeader',
  body: '@Language.ConfirmOrganizationDeleteBody)?',
  callback: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteOrganization", "Administration")',
      data: { organizationId: orgId },
      traditional: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: 'false',
      success: function (result) {
        alert('Delete successfully');
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('Fail');
      }
    });
  }
});
$("#confirmYesBtn").text('@Language.ConfirmActionHeader');
$("#closebutton").text('@Language.CloseButtonLabel');
```

The **Heading** is showing the correct value but the **ConfirmYesBtn** showing the same value, but with some numbers and characters. I am using Swedish culture and want to show the value of Confirm which is **Bekräfta** the Text of Confirm Button  is **Bekr#228;fta**

Is there any way to Unicode the language or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `&` character was lost somehow when you posted your question. Text of a confirm button is: `Bekr&#228;fta` not `Bekr#228;fta`, right?

If so, use `.html` instead of `.text` when setting labels for your buttons so character entities can be decoded by browser, e.g.

```
$("#confirmYesBtn").html('@Language.ConfirmActionHeader');
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/EJ3nZ/

```
// doesn't work
$("#one").text('Bekr&#228;fta');
// works as expected
$("#two").html('Bekr&#228;fta');​
```